# running python script from a bash function and import the bash function

Tags: bash

I've created a `utils.bash` inside which I have a function

```
function run() {
   python some_long_running.py
}
```

I want to import this function in some other script and run the python command. But, doing so doesn't print anything. I believe its because the function waits for python script to finish and then return its output. Can I somehow keep printing the output of the python script to the stdin and stderr.

Comment: You did not show how you "imported" and called the function, nor did you describe what the Python program is doing. Also, your sentence "printing the output of the script to the stdin" simply does not make sense. In general, when you run a command (`python` in your case), the calling process (the bash script executing `run` waits for this child process to finish. This happens with **all** commands. I simply don't understand your problem here. Please provide information and provide a clear, understandable problem description.